# Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Ruby. Webdriver. Mac

Tags: ruby, macos, selenium-chromedriver

Please help!

I am trying to run my testing script using Ruby and Selenium Web driver.

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.navigate.to "google.com"
driver.quit
```

but it gives me an error

```
 Unable to find the chromedriver executable. Please download the server from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)
```

I have installed the chromedriver and unzipped it in the directory ~/webdrivers. And added the path to the chromedriver to the PATH. 
Then I tried to move the chromedriver to ~/bin directory and have it in PATH.

Nothing worked. I still get the error.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

1 - Download the ChromeDriver executable.

2 - Either create your own PATH to a unique folder on your mac or copy the file to an existing PATH directory. To do this:

```
  a - Open up Terminal
  b - Run sudo nano /etc/paths
  c - Enter your password
  d - Go to the bottom of the file and enter the path you wish to add
  e - My PATH looks like: /Users//Documents/WebDriver
  f - Control-x to quit
  g - Y to save
```

To double check, quit Terminal and relaunch it. Run echo $PATH. You should see your newly added path in the stream of other paths already there.

Finally, update your tests to run using ChromeDriver (include code snippet) and run your tests!

---

Another tip: if you use brew on Mac I would recommend `brew install chromedriver`.

re-run "selenium-standalone install" after re-installing

Comment: Please don't only post a link. Links can be taken down, moved, or changed. Post the substance of your solution to your answer.

Comment: @Knetic Done! Thanks for the advice! I am rookie on this :P

Comment: Thanks a lot! homebrew is so easy. Didn't have to set the path.